# How do I fix a crashpad compilation error (for windows)

Tags: windows, compilation, crashpad

tI am following the instructions listed here: https://github.com/chromium/crashpad/blob/master/doc/developing.md

I cloned crashpad from here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/crashpad/crashpad

But I get the following results:

```
D:/Work/GitRepos/ThirdParty/crashpad> gn gen out/default

ERROR at //build/crashpad_buildconfig.gni:56:5: Unable to load "D:/Work/GitRepos/ThirdParty/crashpad/third_party/mini_chromium/mini_chromium/build/compiler.gni".
    import("../third_party/mini_chromium/mini_chromium/build/compiler.gni")
    ^--------------------------------------------------------------------- 
See //BUILD.gn:15:1: whence it was imported. 
import("build/crashpad_buildconfig.gni") 
^--------------------------------------
```

Which is correct. There are no sub-folders under: D:\Work\GitRepos\ThirdParty\crashpad\third_party\mini_chromium

There must be something missing from the configuration instructions(?)  How does one build crashpad for windows?

Comment: You're more likely to reach relevant people if you follow the information in the README at https://chromium.googlesource.com/crashpad/crashpad : there is an issue tracker, and there is a developer mailing list for crashpad.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll take a look there.

Comment: In case anyone else lands here...I resolved this issue, by updated my version of depot_tools.  Then I also had to modifying my PATH to use the version of Python found in depot_tools, and not another one installed on my system.

Comment: @WorldTurnedUpsideDown did not help me